# Invoke-RestMethod Error: Cannot Send Body Type

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, freshdesk

I am trying to GET tickets from Freshdesk using the Invoke-RestMethod. The error I'm receiving is "Invoke-RestMethod: Cannot send a content-body with this verb type". My function looks like this:

```
function opentickets()
{
$Body = @{
#description = $description.Text
email = $email.Text
#subject = $subject.Text
#type = $request.Text
#priority = 1
#status = 2
}
Invoke-RestMethod -uri "https://clasd.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets?" - 
ContentType application/json -Method Get -Body ($Body | ConvertTo-Json)
}
```

The Freshdesk API endpoint to view tickets should return something like the examples that freshdesk gives using curl:

https://clasd.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets?email=[requester_email]

**Update**
If I use the following:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -uri 
"https://clasd.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets? 
email=xyz@clasd.net" -Headers $FDHeaders -ContentType 
 application/json -Method Get
```

I receive the desired outcome. Can I output the result from the Invoke command to something more readable for a user?

Comment: try using `-Method Post` instead of get. You cannot send a body with a get. I can't see the example at your link, can you post the code from there?

Answer (score 6):

For any client, you cannot send a payload (body) with a GET request to a RESTful service.  It used to be that most clients allowed you to do so, but this has since been changed.

Your workaround helps remediate the issue by using query strings instead.  You'll have to look at Freshdesk's documentation to see if they support a POST request for retrieving ticket information, or make sure the query-string approach will suit your needs.

Looks like the filtering tickets by query method is what is recommended:

https://developers.freshdesk.com/api/#filter_tickets

Comment: The HTTP standard allows for GET requests with a body. However, there are many server and proxy implementations that simply do not support that. So in the end, GET with a body is to be avoided :(