# Problems with querying MapQuest free Api with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, rest

I'm trying to get data out of this one
[https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/geocoding-api/reverse/get](MapQuest Reverse Geocode)

```
$ApiKey = "xxxxx" #Add your key here

$Url = "http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/reverse?key=$ApiKey"
$ApiBody = @{ 
  location = @{
    latLng = @{
      'lat' = 55.40988888
      'lng' = 11.39666277
    }
  }
  options = @{
    'thumbMaps' = 'false'
  }
  includeNearestIntersection = 'false'
  includeRoadMetadata = 'true'
}
write-host ( $ApiBody | ConvertTo-Json)

$response =   Invoke-RestMethod $Url -Method get -Headers @{ 'Content-Type' = 'application/json' } -Body $ApiBody 

#TEST 2
$Url = "http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/reverse?key=$ApiKey"
$ApiBody = @{
  'location' = @{
    'latLng' = @{
      'lat'= 55.40988888
      'lng'= 11.39666277
    }
  }
}
#$ApiBody = $ApiBody | ConvertTo-Json

$response =   Invoke-RestMethod $Url -Method Post  -Body $ApiBody 
$response
```

I keep getting a 400 response :/

[image]

When I do it in PostMan it works:

[image: PostMan]

It seems that I don't format the body form correctly !?

Still it wont work

Comment: GET means the request does not have a body.  Post means the request has a body.  You are using GET and should be using Post.  Postman is automatically using POST while PowerShell you have to specify the type.

Comment: It's seems  Powershell `Invoke-RestMethod` GET is blocked body in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49899476/invoke-restmethod-error-cannot-send-body-type)

Comment: I've changed PowerShell to POST 

$Url = "http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/reverse?key=$ApiKey"
$ApiBody = @{
  'location' = @{
    'latLng' = @{
      'lat'= 55.40988888
      'lng'= 11.39666277
    }
  }
}
#$ApiBody = $ApiBody | ConvertTo-Json

$response =   Invoke-RestMethod $Url -Method Post  -Body $ApiBody 
$response 

Still it wont work

Comment: I'd played around with the BODY part ... This works

$response =   Invoke-RestMethod $Url -Method Post -Headers @{ 'Content-Type' = 'application/json' } -Body ( $ApiBody | ConvertTo-Json )

Comment: POST call can send body but I tested GET can't send a body. I think you needs find other method like curl, node.js.

Comment: I tested this command $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/reverse?key=xxxx' -Method GET -Body ($ApiBody|ConvertTo-Json) -ContentType "application/json"

Answer (score 0):

It was a combo of POST/GET and the body not correctly formatted as JSON

End Result is

```
Invoke-RestMethod $Url -Method POST -Headers @{ 'Content-Type' = 'application/json' } -Body ( $ApiBody | ConvertTo-Json )
```